# angular ActivatedRoute.queryParams doesn't allow rxjs operators?

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, rxjs

Hi I have a subscription on the `queryParams` like

```
this.route.queryParams
    .skip(1)
    .subscribe((res: DataParameter) => {})
```

It gives me the type error

> this.route.queryParams.skip is not a function

same goes for the `distincUntilChanged` operator. Is there something I'm missing, in the docs it says it returns an Observable.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you include the operator with `import 'rxjs/add/operator/skip';`?

Comment: thanks!!!...that was a stupid mistake..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you import the operator?

```js
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
```

Because the rxjs package is very large, only a small subset of operators is imported by default.

#### === Update Dec 2017 ===

As of today, pipeable operators are the new and preferred way of importing and using rxjs operators.
For further information, have a look at the [rxjs docs](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md).

```js
import { map, filter, scan } from 'rxjs/operators';
source$.pipe(
  filter(x => x % 2 === 0),
  map(x => x + x),
  scan((acc, x) => acc + x, 0)
)
```